# How do I check an array's bounds and make sure the code does not error in the game "Go" that I am making in Java

Tags: java, arrays, loops, bluej, bounds

```
protected void pressedOnSpace(int row, int col) {

    if (board[row][col] < board[0][0]) {
        canvas.errors = false;
    }

    if (board[row][col] == GoFrame.WHITE) {
        board[row][col] = GoFrame.BLACK;
    }
    else if (board[row][col] == GoFrame.BLACK) {
        board[row][col] = GoFrame.EMPTY;
    }
    else if (board[row][col] == GoFrame.EMPTY) {
        board[row][col] = GoFrame.WHITE;
    }
}
```

I am making the game "Go" for a Java assignment. This is a helper method I'm having issues on. The game is based on arrays and loops. The instructions tell me that I am supposed to implement a bound check and there is a boolean variable "canvas.errors" and if it evaluates to true, a big "X" appears over the board, false is there's no "X". I am supposed to do an array bound check to make sure the "X" does not appear but I am unsure how to go about it because everything I have tried continues to produce an "X" when I click on the board outside of the bounds of the array. I know I am supposed to find all the possible ways the program could error and evaluate those ways to "false" with the variable/function but I cant seem to figure it out. The first "if" statement is what I have as of now for the bound checker after a bunch of tries. Any help would be appreciated as I am a newer coder.

Comment: Can you describe in simple English what a "bounds check" is, in the context of an array?

Comment: It doesn't appear that your code is actually checking bounds at all. Rather, you seem to be attempting to compare the contents of cells -- that's not the same as checking bounds. A goban is 19 cells by 19 cells. Unless I'm misreading your explanation, when the player selects a cell, you should be testing that x >= 0 and x < 20, and the same for y. Are you quite certain you understand your assignment?

Comment: @MarsAtomic I am sorry if the explanation was confusing the first time around. This is just a helper method that replaces white stones with black, black stones with no stone, and no stones with a white stone depending on where the user clicks. That I just made with the if-else statements.

Comment: @MarsAtomic These are the instructions for this specific method:
"If the given column and row positions are a legal location on the board, modifies the location by either changing the stone's color, or by adding or removing a stone. col = The horizontal position of the spot on the board, with 0 representing the left of the board. row = The vertical position of the spot on the board, with 0 representing the top of the board."

Comment: @tgdavies to check if the row and column given in an array is out of bounds or not (not within the set elements of an array). I want to make it so that even though a player may choose a position outside the bounds of an array, an error does not occur

Comment: OK, so as @MarsAtomic says, you need to be checking the values of x and y against the size of the array, and not trying to update the contents of the array if either is out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you just need help structuring your code to perform a very common operation referred to as validation, or in plain English, making sure you handle situations where your user submits invalid information. All you want to do is make sure the X and Y values represent a legitimate cell on your goban so that your code doesn't choke later on when it tries to process an invalid value.

```
protected void pressedOnSpace(int row, int col) {

    if (row >= 0 && row < 20) && (col >= 0 && col < 20) {
        // insert your logic for changing color
    } else {
        // insert your logic for drawing a big fat X over the board
    }
    
}
```